# How can I get the p-value of an estimation by margins using estadd?

Tags: stata

This question is related to another question, I asked at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121984/which-p-value-to-report-in-a-comparison-of-different-logistic-regression-models):
I am running multiple logistic models in `Stata` and want to store the results of the models and of some post-estimations using `margins`. There are two relatively easy possibilities using the ado `estout` (see the [documentation](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/hlp_estadd.html#margins)). However, both lack either the z-statistics or some of the summary statistics. Here is an example:

```
. webuse acmemanuf, clear

. // estadd
. eststo est1: qui logit acceptable i.temp y

. qui estadd margins, dydx(*)

. eststo est2: qui logit acceptable i.temp y i.pressure

. qui estadd margins, dydx(*)

. // margins, post
. qui logit acceptable i.temp y, nolog

. eststo est3: qui margins, dydx(*) post

. qui logit acceptable i.temp y i.pressure, nolog

. eststo est4: qui margins, dydx(*) post

. // Wrong t-statistics using "estadd"
. esttab est1 est2, cells("margins_b t") margin pr2 aic    
----------------------------------------------------------------
                      (1)                       (2)             
               acceptable                acceptable             
                margins_b            t    margins_b            t
----------------------------------------------------------------
acceptable                                                      
1.temp                  0            .            0            .
2.temp            .122275     .8468373     .2366358     1.448193
3.temp           .1028261     .6194538     .0930619     .6025044
y                .0171374     2.752288     .0202188     2.993524
1.pressure                                        0            .
2.pressure                                -.2384807    -1.454117
----------------------------------------------------------------
N                      49                        49             
pseudo R-sq         0.233                     0.271             
AIC                 55.48                     55.10             
----------------------------------------------------------------
Marginal effects

. // Loosing summary statistics using "margins, post" 
. esttab est3 est4, cells("b t") margin pr2 aic

----------------------------------------------------------------
                      (1)                       (2)             

                        b            t            b            t
----------------------------------------------------------------
1.temp                  0            .            0            .
2.temp            .122275     .8600932     .2366358     1.723335
3.temp           .1028261     .6322357     .0930619     .6126009
y                .0171374     4.103384     .0202188     5.118546
1.pressure                                        0            .
2.pressure                                -.2384807    -1.729937
----------------------------------------------------------------
N                      49                        49             
pseudo R-sq                                                     
AIC                     .                         .             
----------------------------------------------------------------
Marginal effects
```

I would like to have a table which shows the summary statistics from the first table and z-statistics from the second table of the examples above.

**EDIT**
I wrote a small local program which does the job and whose results can be captured by `esttab`. Please note that the program code must be slightly modified for models which produce t-statistics instead of z-statistics. If someone could integrate the program into a subroutine for `estadd` as described in the [documentation](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/estadd.html#estadd007) , I am eager to hear it as I only succeded in adding results of linear regression models. Here is my do-file:

```
webuse acmemanuf, clear

program define margzp
    tempname rtab
    tempname tmargins_z
    tempname tmargins_p
    mat `rtab' = r(table)
    mat `tmargins_z' = `rtab'["z", 1..(colsof(`rtab')-1)]
    mat `tmargins_p' = `rtab'["pvalue", 1..(colsof(`rtab')-1)]
    estadd matrix margins_z = `tmargins_z'
    estadd matrix margins_p = `tmargins_p'
end

eststo: logit acceptable i.temp y
estadd margins, dydx(*)
margzp *

eststo: logit acceptable i.temp y i.pressure
estadd margins, dydx(*)
margzp *

esttab, cells((margins_b(fmt(3) star pvalue(margins_p)) ///
    margins_z)) pr2 aic bic star(+ 0.10 * 0.05 ** 0.01 *** 0.001) ///
    postfoot(`"{hline @width}"' ///
    `"Marginal effects, standard errors in parentheses"' `"@starlegend"') ///
```

Which gives the following table:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                      (1)                          (2)                
               acceptable                   acceptable                
                margins_b       margins_z    margins_b       margins_z
----------------------------------------------------------------------
acceptable                                                            
1.temp              0.000               .        0.000               .
2.temp              0.122           0.847        0.237           1.448
3.temp              0.103           0.619        0.093           0.603
y                   0.017**         2.752        0.020**         2.994
1.pressure                                       0.000               .
2.pressure                                      -0.238          -1.454
----------------------------------------------------------------------
N                      49                           49                
pseudo R-sq         0.233                        0.271                
AIC                 55.48                        55.10                
BIC                 63.05                        64.56                
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Marginal effects, standard errors in parentheses
+ p<0.10 * p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

Comment: Could you please comment briefly if you downvote. Maybe, I can reword the question?

Comment: It is not clear whether you have hacked at any of the `esttab` suite of programs or are suggesting that. I'd contact the author (Ben Jann) directly if you want to do that. I don't think he visits here.

Comment: @NickCox I started to modify the ado-files of the `estout` suite, but then I decided that it was too much work for my purpose. Therefore, I only wrote this tiny program and made used some more general `estout` functions to catch the output using `esttab`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example. I am not a 100% sure I incorporated everything that you wanted. If not, please add an example of what you want the table to look like:

```
. sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)

. eststo, title(Index): logit foreign price mpg

Iteration 0:   log likelihood =  -45.03321  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -36.627434  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -36.462562  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood =  -36.46219  
Iteration 4:   log likelihood = -36.462189  

Logistic regression                               Number of obs   =         74
                                                  LR chi2(2)      =      17.14
                                                  Prob > chi2     =     0.0002
Log likelihood = -36.462189                       Pseudo R2       =     0.1903

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     foreign |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       price |    .000266   .0001166     2.28   0.022     .0000375    .0004945
         mpg |   .2338353   .0671449     3.48   0.000     .1022338    .3654368
       _cons |  -7.648111   2.043673    -3.74   0.000    -11.65364   -3.642586
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(est1 stored)

. eststo, title(AMEs): margins, dydx(*) post

Average marginal effects                          Number of obs   =         74
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : Pr(foreign), predict()
dy/dx w.r.t. : price mpg

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       price |   .0000428   .0000166     2.57   0.010     .0000102    .0000754
         mpg |   .0376126   .0074022     5.08   0.000     .0231045    .0521207
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(est2 stored)

. esttab, drop(_cons)

--------------------------------------------
                      (1)             (2)   
                  foreign                   
--------------------------------------------
main                                        
price            0.000266*      0.0000428*  
                   (2.28)          (2.57)   

mpg                 0.234***       0.0376***
                   (3.48)          (5.08)   
--------------------------------------------
N                      74              74   
--------------------------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I want to compare two different, nested models. Therefore, the "Index" estimation is not very important to me. However, I would like to keep the summary statistics like AIC and R2  of the "Index" model, but report the effects and z-statistics of the marginal effects estimation only. I modified my question to make this clearer.